# Why mkfs-like commands seems to be the "commit" for creating new partitions with fdisk?

Tags: usb, partitioning, memory, storage, fdisk

I don't understand this logic behind storage devices: if I delete all the partitions and create new ones with `fdisk` and `fdisk` don't report any erros, why reconnecting the device causes a mounting just like it was before changing the partitions with `fdisk`?

Formatting the partitions with `mkfs`-like commands seems to be the "submit" for `fdisk` operations.

Links with explanations about how storage devices works logically in this context are welcome.

Comment: are you certain you're writing the new partition table to disk before quitting fdisk?  if so maybe you're seeing the OS's cache of the old partition table and need to reboot to be 100% certain your OS sees the new partition table.

Comment: for absolute certainty that your OS is updated you can reboot between each committed fdisk operation.  ie, (1) delete partition table in fdisk, (2) reboot & check that no partitions are seen, (3) create new partition table, (4) reboot again to update.

Comment: even after `fdisk` run `sync` this system cache may exist?

Comment: it's not supposed to, but it's possible.  you tagged the question `usb`, so disconnecting / reconnecting the usb cable might be enough to force the kernel to reload the partition table.  but reboot is the only guarantee afaik.

Comment: In most cases, fdisk deals with only the partition table on a disk, which is separate from the partitions themselves and the filesystem they contain. It's just like the situation with filesystem formatting: unless the command specifically says to do so, re-formatting a partition does not affect (for the most part), the actual data out on the disk sectors in the partition. That's how disk recovery software is able to work.

Comment: To expand kreemoweet's comment: `fdisk` deals with partition table which is like a table of contents. When you remove partition entry, the content (i.e. filesystem) is still intact, you only lose track where it begins. If you then create new partition entry **with the same starting sector**, it will have the old filesystem – well, unless the new partition is smaller than the filesystem, but if it's at least the same size, then you can mount it and access your data. **Did you create the new partition(s) at the same starting sector(s) as the old one(s) was (were)?**